Typo3 11.5 - Middleware/Event - Modify Access for FE-Groups
I' looking for an PSR14 Event / PSR15 Middleware to use for modifying the fetched ce's in terms of change the access rights (fe-groups) for show/hide in the frontend for Typo3 11.5. So far I haven't found any, is that even possible?
